# How to manually control the indivdual part file size in PySpark?

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a problem statement which states to "find a way how PySpark data frames can be written to the disk while manually controlling the size of individual part-files". All the help is appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: Depends on your "size" definition... You can use [`spark.sql.files.maxRecordsPerFile`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#spark-sql) to control the number of rows, Files may still end up being of different size in bytes.

Comment: @DileeprajnarayanThumula Yes